# DB schema for updating downstream sources?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I want a table to be sync-able by a web API.

For example,

```
GET /projects?sequence_latest=2113&limit=10

[{"state":"updated", "id":12,"sequence":2116},
{"state":"deleted" "id":511,"sequence":2115}
{"state":"created", "id":601,"sequence":2114}]
```

What is a good schema to achieve this?

I intend this for Postgresql with Django **ORM**, which uses surrogate keys. Presence of an ORM may kill answers like unions.

---

I can come up with only half-solutions.

1. I could have a modified_time column, but we cannot convey deletions.
2. I could have a table for storing deleted IDs, when returning 10 new/updated rows, I could return all the deleted rows between them. But this works only when the latest change is an insert/update and there are a moderate number of deleted rows.
3. I could set a deleted flag on the row and null the rest, but its kinda bad schema design to set all columns nullable.
4. I could have another table that stores ID, modification sequence number and state(new, updated, deleted), but its another table to maintain and setting sequence numbers cause contentions; imagine n concurrent requests querying for latest ID.

Comment: How about simply a `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` column? Where the last 2 are nullable in case no updates have been made. That way you can store everything in a single table, get the state and don't have to hack too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an ORM you want simple(ish) and if you're serving the data via an API you want quick.

To go through your suggested options:

1. Correct, so this doesn't help you. You could have a deleted flag in your main table though.
2. This seems quite a random way of doing it and breaks your insistence that there be no UNION queries.
3. Not sure why you would need to NULL the rest of the column here? What benefit does this bring?
4. I would strongly advise against having a table that has a modification sequence number. Either this means that you're performing a lot of analytic queries in order to find out the most recent state or you're updating the same rows multiple times and maintaining a table with the same PK as your normal one. At that point you might as well have a deleted flag in your main table.

Essentially the design of your API gives you one easy option; you should have everything in the same table because all data is being returned through the same method. I would follow your point 2 and [Wolph's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507070/db-schema-for-updating-downstream-sources#comment43627086_27507070), have a `deleted_on` column in your table; making it look like:

```
create table my_table ( 
     id ... primary key
   , <other_columns>
   , created_on date
   , modified_on date
   , deleted_on date
     );
```

I wouldn't even bother updating all the other columns to be NULL. If you want to ensure that you return no data create a view on top of your table that nulls data where the `deleted_on` column has data in it. Then, your API only accesses the table through the view.

If you are *really*, *really* worried about space *and* the volume of records *and* will perform regular database maintenance to ensure that both are controlled then maybe go with option 4. Create a second table that has the state of each ID in your main table and actually delete the data from your main table. You then can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the main table to get the data. When there is no data that ID has been deleted. Honestly, this is overkill until you know whether you will definitely require it.

You don't mention why you're using an web API for data-transfers; but, if you're going to be transferring a lot of data or using this for internal systems only it might be worth using a lower-level transfer mechanism.

Comment: Your question on my point 3: that soft-deletes where you can still retrieve data "deleted" by users run afoul of privacy laws in places.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You need to remove the data and just keep the ID then.